# How do I allow only certain IP's to view webpages?

Tags: php, arrays, ip

I'm trying to get a PHP script to work where it compares the IP of the person against a text file(one IP per line). If the person's IP is not in the text file, then he gets redirected to declined.html. I know I could use .htaccess for this but the IP list could get really, really long.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
<?php
$ipArray = file('ip.txt');
unset($allowed);
foreach ($ipArray as $ipTest) if (substr_count($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],trim($ipTest))     != "0") $allowed = true;
if ($allowed != true) {
header('location: /declined.html');  // the banned display page
die();
}
?>
```

I want to be able to call this script in every page that I only want certain IP's to see, this is what I'm trying to call it with:

```
<? include('ip_allow.php'); ?>
```

When I call the PHP script in the HTML page when my IP is NOT in ip.txt, it does not redirect me to /declined.html! How can I fix this? Again, my question is not how to use .htaccess, but how to fix my script! Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't `unset($allowed);` be `$allowed = false;`?

Comment: Why not use `.htaccess`?

Comment: I don't want to fill up htaccess with tons of IP's

Comment: @user1008120 how is filling up a text file any different?

Answer (score 6):

For IP filtering, it's best to do it as early as possible in the processing chain. In order of preference:

1. router
2. firewall
3. webserver
4. script

Most likely you don't have access to the router or firewall levels, but you CAN use Apache's mod_rewrite to have a dynamic block using an external file. Set up your "enabled IPs" file as follows:

```
a.b.c.d ALLOWED
b.c.d.e ALLOWED
c.d.e.f ALLOWED
etc...
```

It's basically "key value", where the key is the IP address

Then your mod_rewrite rules (I've numbered them for reference)

```
1. RerwriteMap ipfiltermap txt:/path/to/your/ips/list
2. RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} (.*)
3. RewriteCond %{ipfiltermap:%1} !ALLOWED
4. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/declined.html
5. RewriteRule .* /forbidden.html [L]
```

They work as follows:

1. Defines the allowed IPs as a "key value" pair, where the keys are the allowed IPs, and the value is the word "ALLOWED", as a mapping named "ipfiltermap"
2. Captures the remote address of the current request (the client IP)
3. Using the IP captured in step 2, look it up in the ipfiltermap, and see if the the IP does NOT have the word 'ALLOWED'
4. Specifically exempt your 'declined' page from the IP enforcement - if this wasn't here, disabllowed IPs would enter an infinite redirect loop
5. If all 3 of the RewriteConds match, then the user is from a forbidden IP, and should be redirected to the fobidden page.

Relevant Apache docs for all this are [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap).

Comment: Wait so I can use this in .htaccess and it will work the same?

Comment: Yeah, it can go into .htaccess, or a .conf file.

Comment: Internal server error, I put it in htaccess as:
RerwriteMap ipfiltermap txt:/ip.txt
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} (.*)
RewriteCond %{ipfiltermap:%1} !ALLOWED
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/declined.html
RewriteRule .* /forbidden.html [L]

Comment: Er, imagine a line break after every rewrite rule

Comment: I don't have access. :/ Maybe this server sucks, I'm getting liquidweb hosting soon, they should have better support on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you place your configuration in your Apache configuration directly, it won't incur the speed penalties of `.htaccess` lookups -- but that would mean you'd need to reload the Apache configuration whenever the list is modified. (Though [Marc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857279/how-do-i-allow-only-certain-ips-to-view-webpages/7857317#7857317) avoids this very nicely.)

The [`mod_authz_host.c`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/2.2.x/modules/aaa/mod_authz_host.c) is optimized for moderately fast searching. If you're reading a *text file* in your script every execution, you're already several times slower than Apache. Apache reads the configuration *once*, converts the IP addresses to a binary format *once*, and can then use very fast integer arithmetic to determine if hosts are allowed or not.

Furthermore, it's already debugged and working. It'd take you less time to deploy it than it would to find the bug in your current code -- and even then, your current code would -- *on every access-controlled request* -- re-read (and re-parse into an array) the textual description of IP addresses, convert the IP address from the remote peer into a text version, and then perform a very slow text-based comparison over the entire array.

If speed is of real importance, then you should investigate doing the access control via your system firewall. `iptables` has optimized routines to find matching IP addresses among a list of allowed or denied hosts and won't waste any time performing any protocol analysis. Of course, this is a much heavier all-or-nothing approach that would require an annoying separation of content among listening ports if some content is available for all.

Answer (score 0):

The `file()` command includes the `\n` character at the end of each line, so each line is actually something like `0.0.0.0\n` which is returning false every time.

Use this:

```
$ipArray = file('ip.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // Try specifying an ABSOLUTE path to this file.
$allowed = false; // Rather than unset($allowed), this will prevent notice errors too!
foreach ($ipArray as $ipTest) if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $ipTest) $allowed = true;
```

Also just to point out in your header line, `Location` should start with a capital letter and you should specify a *full URI* to the file:

```
header('Location: http://example.com/declined.html');
```

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned off? If it's not working then there should be either a warning or fatal error popping up.

Comment: I am using <html>
<? include('ip_allow.php'); ?>
<center>
hellooooooo
</div>
</center>
</html>

Comment: So all I see is the "helloooo" part

Comment: That div shouldnt be there, haha.

Comment: You're running a header call *after* you've sent output? This needs to be at the very beginning of the file before any output is ever sent.

Comment: I made the code changes and I'm calling it with
<? include('ip_allow.php'); ?>
<html>
<center>
hellooooooo
</center>
</html>

Comment: All I can say is trying debugging it by using `var_dump()` to see what your IP and the IPs in the file actually are, or use Marc's htaccess method above.

Comment: Hey I figured it out. If I go directly to ip_allow.php in the browser it works, and if I put it in index.php with other stuff it works too. It's ONLY when I try putting it in a HTML file that it decides not to work. I wonder why?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you have files in the wrong directory, or PHP not working or some other more basic configuration issue, since I tested your code and it works fine for me.